# Why :empty don't corrent work with input?

Tags: css

http://caniuse.com/#search=empty

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty

```
input:empty{border:1px solid green}
<input type= "text" >
```

In Chrome input always has green border (when value is not empty too...)

https://jsfiddle.net/5aczpv3j/5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of a form element isn't text (as such) and self-closing elements cannot hold child elements, `<input type="text"/>` will therefore ALWAYS be `:empty` ...

```css
p,input,textarea{
    border: 3px solid blue;
    line-height:2em;
    min-height:2em;
}
p:empty,input:empty,textarea:empty{
    border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<p>Not empty</p>
<p></p>
<p> </p>
<form action="">
    <input type="text"/>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" value="Empty"/>
    <br/>
    <textarea></textarea>
    <br/>
    <textarea> </textarea>
</form>
```

Notice how the paragraphs and textarea with spaces in are not empty (therefore blue border) while the input field returns empty, even when you use the value attribute?

Why not use :valid and/or :invalid (IE10+) or else, use JavaScript?

Answer (score 3):

`:empty` looks for child elements, adding text to an `<input>` element doesn't change this. The premise of your question is flawed.